# Getting a 500 Internal Server Error using render_template and Flask

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask

I am trying to use Flask to render an HTML template. I had it working great and now each time I get a `500 Internal Server Error`. If I replace the `render_template` function just a string, things work fine. What am I doing wrong?

**init**.py :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template("main.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

main.html in /templates/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<p>test</p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template_folder has to be defined where the static files are located.

If the main.html file is in the same folder as the init.py, then include the following code:

```
import os

project_root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
template_path = os.path.join(project_root, './')

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_path)
```

Hopefully it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample actually works on my end.

- What version of flask are you running?
- are you sure that you are accessing the URL at port 5000 (the default) and not an application on port 80?
- Are old instances of the server still running, that may be colliding with attempts to re-launch the server?

Comment: Flask Version: 0.10.1, URL that generates the Internal Server Error: http://127.0.0.1:5000/. I am using PyCharm and closed all connections.