# Getting a 500 Internal Server Error even with fixes as recommended in a couple of similar questions

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn, systemd

I'm having same issue as described in these two questions/answers:

[Python WSGI + Flask render_template - 500 Internal Server Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140116/python-wsgi-flask-render-template-500-internal-server-error)

[Getting a 500 Internal Server Error using render_template and Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698493/getting-a-500-internal-server-error-using-render-template-and-flask)

and I've narrowed it to the following:

Here's the file structure:

```
../project/
    project.py
    templates/
        about.html
```

I'm still getting this error (shorten):

```
● project.service - Gunicorn instance to serve project
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/project.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-02-15 06:28:46 UTC; 3min 28s ago
 Main PID: 3942 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 1151)
   CGroup: /system.slice/project.service
           ├─3942 /home/dev/project/project_env/bin/python3.6 /home/dev/project/project_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:project.sock -m 007 wsgi
           ├─3967 /home/dev/project/project_env/bin/python3.6 /home/dev/project/project_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:project.sock -m 007 wsgi
           ├─3968 /home/dev/project/project_env/bin/python3.6 /home/dev/project/project_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:project.sock -m 007 wsgi
           └─3969 /home/dev/project/project_env/bin/python3.6 /home/dev/project/project_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:project.sock -m 007 wsgi

Feb 15 06:29:17 project gunicorn[3942]:     return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
Feb 15 06:29:17 project gunicorn[3942]:   File "/home/dev/project/project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
Feb 15 06:29:17 project gunicorn[3942]:     template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
Feb 15 06:29:17 project gunicorn[3942]:   File "/home/dev/project/project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 117, in load
Feb 15 06:29:17 project gunicorn[3942]:     source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
Feb 15 06:29:17 project gunicorn[3942]:   File "/home/dev/project/project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 60, in get_source
Feb 15 06:29:17 project gunicorn[3942]:     return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
Feb 15 06:29:17 project gunicorn[3942]:   File "/home/dev/project/project_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
Feb 15 06:29:17 project gunicorn[3942]:     raise TemplateNotFound(template)
Feb 15 06:29:17 project gunicorn[3942]: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: about.html
```

So the issue as far as I can tell, is that last line

```
Feb 15 06:29:17 project gunicorn[3942]: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: about.html
```

I don't understand why, even though the files/folders are there. The closest I could find is this comment:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56589998/12070612

```py
ENV = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(str(root_path / 'templates')))
template = ENV.get_template(your_template_name)
```

But if I add the "ENV=..." lines to my project.py file, then Gunicorn complaints and fails to start process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways in Flask to render HTML. You could simply generate that HTML directly from the Python code similar to what you have done for the `home` route or you could use a templating language like Jinja.

What you have written in the `about` route is the `render_template` function. The way `render_template` works is by reading an HTML file with the name you pass as a parameter and renders that template. In you case, you have called the `render_template` method and asked it to render a template called `about.html` but since the template does not exist, it fails to load and throws an exception.

Create an `about.html` file at the same level as your app.py file and type in something in it and try to render. It should work.

To read more on `render_template` check out the documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates) or read the getting started tutorial for Flask [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/)

Comment: I do have a file called "about.html" but it is within a subfolder called "/templates".  I am unsure if the template_path, as written above, points correctly to that folder.  It should result in "template_path = myapp/templates".  I was under the impression that by default Flask looks for that folder so I first had no "template_path" but kept getting this error and tried the above, based on the answers to the other questions I linked to also above.

Comment: Could you share the structure of your application folder as well as the templates folder?

Comment: Yes, will add to original question above.  Thank you!!

Comment: @acakaliman The issue is with the path generated in the variable `template_path `. In your case, that would amount to `/home/dev/apponto_app/./` as you are joining the path of `project_root` with `./` instead of templates.

In your case, since the templates folder is in the same directory, you could simply skip it as template_path defaults to `templates` folder or change `./` to `templates` for it to work fine